# javascript page to collect information on different system

Tags: html, javascript

I'm a JS newbie and I'm starting a project for a simple page that reads IP/username/password and then with this information send several web requests to a reporting server using a predefined API that requests report generation.

This is how the API looks:

```
https://<IP>:<PORT>/api/create?username=<USER>&password=<PASS>&database=<DB>&action=archive&reporttype=1 ..... 10
```

How can I start a webpage that reads the variables, prepares the script and after user clicking a button starts sending the web requests (I believe using iframes) to request the report generation?

Comment: As you can see the webpage is HTTPS.

Comment: This API has you pass your password as a $_GET parameter..?

Comment: Yes.. I just need to request an URL (GET) providing the username and password and it start generating the report for the specific user.